# Sidebars with 100% height

Tags: css, html, height, sidebar

I have uploaded example here: http://vizakenjack.narod2.ru/testpage2.html

My problem is sidebars with 100% height. If the content is only 1 line of text, sidebars should fill all the screen. Otherwise, if the content is more that screen, sidebars should scroll down to the end of page.

I have tried to set position:relative to body. Sidebars are ok when content is a big article, but when article is small, they aren't fit to 100% height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic case for http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/. Read it, bookmark it, keep it nearby at all times.

Comment: but I dont use footer. Is it still same?

Comment: Yes, footer is totally optional.

Comment: Which of that examples should I use? I have looked at http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_3.html , but if I remove footer, sidebars arent fit into bottom of page.

Comment: Ah, I see - you want columns to reach the bottom of the window even if content isn't long enough. Try adding _padding-bottom:9999px_ and _margin-bottom:-9999px_ to the styles for your two sidebar columns.